# Getting message "This page has insecure content" while accessing drupal site using HTTPS://?

Tags: drupal-7

I have developed Drupal site . But when I access my site using HTTPS://  browser gives me a message  "This page has insecure content" . I have putted my site data on secure site .

I load JS file in that page for some purpose.
    So,Is it JS file issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it should be JS or CSS issue, unless you include them using absolute URLs:
For example if you add the following lines in your theme's template file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yoursite/mystyle.css">
<script src="http://yoursite/myScript.js"></script>
```

This serves the JavaScript through `http` instead of `https`. Instead you should use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
```

notice that the URLs in the second piece of code contains relative URL, and would serve the files with the same protocol with which the site is accessed via a browser.

If this is not the case, you have to scan through all the links on the page, and find the links which are start with the format `http://...` instead of `https://...`. This problem arises when a browser finds that not all content of the page is being served using encryption.
Hope that makes sense. Please feel free to ask further queries.

Comment: I will check links in my site and put the result as early as possible

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you might have some assets (css or javascript) loaded from "non secure" source (using http protocol instead of https).